# Flutter login with google and firebase doesn't work on Play Store

Tags: flutter, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Before you say, I have already added the google console subscription key to my firebase:

[image]

[image]

added the upload and debug key. In Google Cloud I can see these keys and everything seems OK, the Oauth consent screen looks ok (but I didn't send the app icon). google-services.json is updated in my project. tests in debug and run --release work, but when I send it to the play store in closed, internal tests it always gives api 10 error. (I recently updated the upgrade key in the console, but it has already been accepted and my apps are being signed with that key.).

I'm checking the created apks and they have the sha1 upload key correctly.

Please, my project is in production and is receiving negative ratings.

My last attempt is to wait for the consent screen to be approved by adding the standard logo and wait 4 to 6 weeks.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale pt-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
```

Trying to log in with Google and Firebase on Android, on IOS it works smoothly, but on Android it fails.

Comment: Adjusted!
For anyone who has this problem one day, understand that you also need to add the legacy signing key, so you will have 4 keys, debug, upload, signature (legacy and new).